# How to open a pdf at a specific page from ASP.Net MVC using iframes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I have an ASP.NET C# application using MVC. I need to open a PDF file at a specific page in an `iframe`. I will have to search for a text inside the PDF and open the PDF at the page where the text occurs. How do I do this?

I have tried [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). But was not able to implement it. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Also tried using Acrobat and AFORMAUTLib, but was not able to.

Comment: How are you opening the PDF - in an Acrobat view? So you just want to specify the start point to display when opening an Acrobat view? Or are you rendering the PDF to an image on the server and displaying that, or something else?

Comment: Am using the acrobat view only. I tried mentioning "#page=2", but that did not work for my iframe. Am displaying the pdf directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe Reader allows "URL Parameters":

[Here's the Adobe documentation](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf)

And here's the option for searching a document:
search=wordList
Opens the Search UI and performs a search for the specified word list in the document. Matching words are highlighted in the document.
The words must be enclosed in quotes and separated by spaces; for example:

```
#search=”word1 word2”
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Similarly is there any option to search words in MS word, excel and text files?

Comment: I am not aware of any options like this for MS Word or Excel, I thinks it's only supported by Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct with respect to searching the document. For display, the mime type alone should be sufficient for most web browsers to display it. Try making the src of your iframe the virtual path to the pdf.

If you need to actually create the PDF, I have done this with iTextSharp--which you mentioned. I could show you how to do it if you'd like. To do so, I need to know what you are trying to do.